# СПП: придаточное причины?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Военные были, потому что война есть.

Расчлененное СПП, придаточное причины?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это придаточное причины. Связующий элемент — комплексный союз *потому что*, с помощью которого выражается семантика причины.